# Short vowel symbol, as in "kızların"?

Tags: symbols

How do I typeset the short `i` vowel, as in this Turkish word, `kızların`?

Answer (score 10):

I was able to typeset it simply by using utf8 and copying and pasting from your question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
kızların
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried copy & paste before, but without the utf8 command.

Answer (score 8):

And, if UTF-8 is unavailable, isn't this just what the \i command produces?

Comment: Yes, both utf8 and `\i` look identical on my system. (Note that `utf8` isn't always the same as `UTF-8`, but don't ask me why and how)